# Change Sigmoid output to probability

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I already trained a neural network with the last layer using sigmoid. If I can not retrain the network with softmax, can I change the final predictions as probability? Now the output of
`pred = fin_model.predict_proba(x_train)`
is like

```
array([[0.65247375, 0.45892698],
       [0.65919983, 0.4590024 ],
       [0.15964866, 0.47771254],
       [0.53297156, 0.47564888],
       [0.16078213, 0.4779702 ]], dtype=float32)
```

The sum of each one like `0.6524+0.4589` is not 1, and thus can not be a probability. Is there a way to change it to probabilities?

Comment: Are you doing a 2 class classification for 5 rows of data? Is that why the shape of the pred = (5,2)?

Comment: If all you want is to convert the sigmoid output into probabilities, then you can perform a softmax operation on the sigmoid outputs. this will make the outputs to add to 1

Comment: Probability of what?

Comment: Why can you not retrain the network? If you trained it with the wrong activation, the outputs are likely to be pretty bad even if you convert them to probabilities now (since the network wasn't trained properly).

Comment: 1. I am doing a 2 class classification. The 5 rows of data are what I selected, there are more than 5 rows. 2. And by probability, I mean for each row of data, the sum equals 1, so it can be interpreted as the probability that this data x belongs to class 0 or 1. 3. The reason I can not retrain the network is that is it very time-consuming, the outputs are not bad now, I just want to calculate AUC based on the outputs now. 4. I will try to perform a softmax operation. Thank you guys!

Comment: @MH563 Then, a baseline approach that comes to mind is to simply normalize the rows. Did you try it, was it insufficient?

Answer (score 0):

The `Sigmoid` function always returns a value between 0 and 1 and mainly used in `binary classification`. `Sigmoid` activation function will mark one class as `close to 0 (<=0.5)` and other `close to 1 (>0.5)`.

To use sigmoid, you need to define final layer as:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation_function='sigmoid'))
```

However you can also use `Softmax` activation for `binary classification`. `Softmax` converts a vector of values to a probability distribution which gives output vector in range (0, 1) and sum to 1.

It can be declared in final layer as :

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation_function='softmax'))
```

You can get more details on [softmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/softmax) and [sigmoid](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/sigmoid) here.